# Is it possible to run Weblogic with 8gb heap size in a 64bit java/linux environment

Tags: java, weblogic, 64-bit, heap-memory, weblogic-10.x

Setup:
 64bit Linux
 64bit SUN Jvm 1.6.0_20
 Weblogic 10.3

Is it possible to run Weblogic 10.3 in this setup with a maximum heap size of 8gb? We have recived answers from oracle support that states that it might not be possible to address more than 4gb with this setup.

Please submit any official links that support any statements that it is possible to run this setup with more than 4gb of heap size. We can not find any documentation of any limits of heap size when running with this setup.

Thanx

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 cases to your query:

**1. Does it work? Can 8 Gb Heap be addressed?**

Sun JDK itself on 64-bit Linux with JDK 1.6 does not limit you to 4 Gb. See [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/HotSpotFAQ.html#64bit_heap). This is without Weblogic.

A similar config (Again Sun/Linux/Jdk 1.6 minus Weblogic) has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559433/benefits-drawbacks-to-running-64-bit-jvm-on-64-bit-linux-server) which tests heaps of 7 - 20 Gb.

One suggestion I have is to try it out, set your Xmx to 8G and see if it shows the heap in the Console as having size 8G. I have not tried this myself.

**2. Will Oracle support any JVM related issues in your configuration in the future?**

I think you might be limited by what official support Oracle provides you. The official [Oracle docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs103/103_over/overview.html) dont seem to suggest this limit of 4 Gb. Another 2 links on the Oracle forums are [here](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5307218) and [here](http://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=899419) which again suggest larger heaps work.